# How to use a TPrintdialog effectively?

Tags: delphi, firebird

Hello I came across this problem a few months back and had time today to check out how to do it. I have a TDbgrid in which I apply a filter to filter contents of a Firebird database. I would like to print out the content after filtering it. I had researched and studied and this what I came up so far:

I put a Tprintdialog component on the page along with a Tbutton and had this code on it:

```
procedure Tviewrecord.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 with PrintDialog1.Create(nil) do
    try
      if Execute then
        Dbgrid4.print;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
```

Problem is that when I am compiling, there is an error on the "print: part of the code.

Thanks.

Comment: "There is an error". Don't be shy. What exactly is the error? And since the line of code you indicate has nothing to do with `TPrintDialog`, why did you give the question the title that you did. Perhaps you should be asking, "How do I print a `TDBGrid` component?"

Comment: Hi David thanks for the reply. Yes I would like to print a tdbgrid content. I posted here a few days back and tried searching it for myself but it seems it wasn't sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code fails to compile for the rather prosaic reason that the `TDBGrid` control does not have a `Print` [method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGrid_Methods). You'll need to write the printing code yourself, or find a third party component with printing capabilities.

Comment: Thanks. I am just afraid of posting as I may not post a good question.